# Preferred Semantics for CXF JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-rs

I was wondering what the preferred semantics are for `jaxrs:server` configurations in a CXF XML context file.

For example, if I have two service implementations for users and orders, and they're accessible from a relative path `"/user"` and `"/order"`.

Would I configure the services this way:

```
<jaxrs:server id="userService" address="/user">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="com.example.UserServiceImpl />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<jaxrs:server id="orderService" address="/order">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="com.example.OrderServiceImpl />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Or this way:

```
<jaxrs:server id="appService" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <!-- 
            Path configured using @Path annotations on the class definition:

            @Path(value="/user")
            public class UserServiceImpl {...}
        -->
        <bean class="com.example.UserServiceImpl />
        <bean class="com.example.OrderServiceImpl />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

It seems like it's only a semantic difference. The second way allows us to not repeat the providers. But I was wondering what I should be considering when performing this configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: It generally makes sense to group restful services as 'Resource' and typically there will be a one @path at the resource level like '/user' and one for each method like '/add', '/delete' etc. so to me the First option in your post makes sense.                        that said it all depends on the requirement at hand ...

Answer (score 1):

I use the second way and try to group services together if they relate... if you can get orders for specific user, then they relate. So I usually have one "v1" api server (versioning support), one for documentation of it (there I use different providers or extension mappings), one for specialized (like admin with more strict security) access, etc.
But i would use some address and not leave it empty, for example "api" or version "v1" at least.

In other way, your cxf.xml can be full of jaxrs servers. And if they relate, there is little chance that they will need different providers, mappings, extensions.

But this question is about opinion and perhaps will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually group them if they have same base address 
lets say we have resource URLs like this

```
<jaxrs:server id="userService" address="api/user">
</jaxrs:server>

<jaxrs:server id="orderService" address="api/order">
</jaxrs:server>
```

as

```
<jaxrs:server id="appService" address="/api">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <!-- 
            @Path(value="/user")
         -->
        <bean class="com.example.UserServiceImpl />
        <bean class="com.example.OrderServiceImpl />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
```

and individually incase they have different Base URLs 
like

```
/profile/user
/cart/orders
```